I can not select or add a database name in connection manager for VS 2022
I am new to SSIS and I have to add a connection for SQL destination server. But, I cant see any names or databases to add there.
The server name was correct. When I click on test connection, it says something about native server client 11. Can someone help? Iam using VS 2022 version 17.10.33
enter image description here
here is the part where I was unable to see any names of my database.

it says something about native server client 11. You should probably uninstall that and replace it with something modern. SNAC11 hasn't had any updates since SQL Server 2012 days and Microsoft stopped shipping it at all as of SQL Server 2022. If you're using OLE DB then you probably want to go with Microsoft OLE DB Driver 19 for SQL Server.

Can you please elaborate on what to do exactly? I am kinda new to ssis so I dont want to mess up anything.

Installing new drivers isn't going to "mess up" SSIS, @EshwarYashwanth ; they're drivers, they're an OS installation.

Thank you very much. The issue has been resolved..

You should write how you solved it @EshwarYashwanth
